# AngularJS: Adding other directives via directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a simple pop-up indicator for when a form input has an invalid value.

Right now, I have a service which handles setting the form values to invalid based upon the results of a call to a server:

```
var item = form[error.PropertyName];
item.$setValidity('error', false);
item.ErrorMessage = error.Message;
```

So on these models I'm setting a property called 'ErrorMessage' to be whatever was sent from the server.

To get that message to popup, I've created this directive which uses the angular-ui bootstrap tooltip directive:

```
myApp.directive('validationPopup', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 10000,
        terminal: true,
        require: '^form',
        compile: function compile($element, $attrs) {
            delete ($attrs['validationPopup']);
            $element.removeAttr('validation-popup');

            $element.attr('tooltip', '{{ErrorMessage}}');
            $element.attr('tooltip-trigger', 'focus');

            return {
                pre: function (scope, element, attrs, formCtrl) { },
                post: function (scope, element, attrs, formCtrl) {
                    $compile(element)(scope);
                    scope.$watch(function () { return (formCtrl[attrs.name] == undefined) ? undefined : formCtrl[attrs.name].$invalid; }, function (invalid) {
                        if (invalid != undefined) {
                            scope.ErrorMessage = formCtrl[attrs.name].ErrorMessage || '';
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    };
```

Since I don't have a lot of experience making directives, and since I've basically cobbled this together from various other answers on here, my question is is this the correct way of adding other directives to an existing element?  It appears to be working correctly; however, I wasn't sure if I was going to run into issues down the line (or performance problems).